# what's wrong with this jest test setup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a React app and I'm trying to create a basic Jest unit test.  I've created a basic Calculator class like this within a Calculator.js file:

```
class Calculator{
    add(num1, num2){
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
export default Calculator;
```

At the same level, I've created a new Jest unit test named Calculator.test.js like this:

```
import './Calculator';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(new Calculator().add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

However, when the Jest test harness runs, the following error gets output:

> ```
> ReferenceError: Calculator is not defined
>
>   3 |
>   4 | test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
> > 5 |   expect(new Calculator().add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
>     |              ^
>   6 | });
>   7 |
>
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/services/Calculator.test.js:5:14)
> ```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with this particular implementation?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your `Calculator.test.js`:

```js
import Calculator from './Calculator';
```

---

Empty import (as in `import './Calculator';`) only loads the module, but doesn’t actually import anything.

Comment: Ya your not declaring `Calculator` - a plain import doesn’t create the Calculator variable - Denis’s modification will make this work